# Laravel Mix: What is the benefit of extracting vendors?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

My minified bundle size is 246kb.  I am seeing if I can getting smaller and I read that extracting vue and jquery using `mix.extract(['vue', 'jquery']);` can help do this.  I added this to webpack.mix.js` and now it created 2 files rather than 1.  It made: 1) app.js which is 161kb and  2) vendor.js which is 180kb.  What is the benefit of this if both need to be included in the page anyways?

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly abut **caching unchanged files.** For example: while you developing app you are changing the files, adding your own code to your project and then **recompile** them all together. But vendors are the core libraries which **you are never edit their code again.** So there is no need to compile them again and download all source code in app.js file. Thus when you extract vendors which they are unchanged files then your cached content size will increase and it also decrease download time of your application because of less changed files must be downloaded again.

Answer (score 2):

It helps you to optimize the file size of the files that client needed to download. Thus speed up the page loading speed even you have updated your site.

Check the [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#vendor-extraction).

> One potential downside to bundling all application-specific JavaScript with your vendor libraries is that it makes long-term caching more difficult. For example, a single update to your application code will force the browser to re-download all of your vendor libraries even if they haven't changed.